# Find consecutive occurrences of numbers

Tags: sql

I have a table like this(example)：

| Id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 4 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 13 | 4 |
| 14 | 4 |
| 15 | 4 |

I am using PieCloudDB Database.

I want to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively, and I tried this query, but it doesn't output all the results I'm expecting.

```
SELECT num
FROM (
  SELECT num,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY id) AS number_row_number
  FROM logs
) AS subquery
WHERE row_number - number_row_number >= 2
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: Can there be gaps in the ID?

Comment: No, the IDs are continuous.@Stu

Comment: @JonasMetzler that Fiddle [doesn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/afXjfav1), your order by is non-determinate.

Comment: @Stu Yes, you're right. I was on the wrong track. Forget my idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following query.

You can take advantage of having no gaps in the Id, having 3 consecutive numbers only requires that a number exists with a variance of +1 & -1.

```
select distinct num
from t 
where exists (select * from t t2 where t2.num = t.num and t2.id = t.id + 1)
and exists (select * from t t2 where t2.num = t.num and t2.id = t.id - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but your answer seems to have a slight problem. When querying my sample data, it didn't output '4', whereas in fact, '4' also appears consecutively three times.

Answer (score 0):

There might be duplicate occurrences of numbers that appear three or more times, so it would be better to use "DISTINCT".

You can try this query in your database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT num as ConsecutiveNums
FROM (
  SELECT num,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM logs
) pieclouddb
GROUP BY num, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT num
FROM (
  SELECT num,
         count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY id) AS cnt
  FROM logs
) AS subquery
where cnt >= 2
GROUP BY num;
```